# How do you truncate string without word wrapping it (no word wrap)?

Tags: jspdf

I found the method `splitTextToSize()` but it only does the word wrap.  I don't want word wrap, I want characters wrap instead.

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', [612, 1008]);
const text = 'Bread Used Car';
const values = pdf.splitTextToSize(text, 72);

console.log(values);
```

I get the output as `["Bread Used", "Car"]`.

I don't want the text to be broken down by whitespace or word wrap.  I want it to truncate by characters instead.  Like this below.

`["Bread Used C", "ar"]`

Is there a jsPDF method for that?  No, then how can it be done instead?